# Extract backgroud url on <style> tag by Scrapy

Tags: css, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** tag style  by scarpy:

```
<style>
 #main_container {
      background: #f50 url('https://google.com/sample.jpg') top center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

and

```
<div id="main_container">
   some text
</div>
```

I try find my answer but i didn't find anything.
Thank you so much

Comment: Show your code? How did you try?

Comment: response.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']/@style").get() But i know it's not correct because it doesn't return on scrapy shell

Comment: You won't get it in this way as `style` is not an attribute of HTML-node located in `body` in your case, but a CSS-property declared in `head`.  You can try to check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586331/scrapy-how-to-get-the-css-rule-for-a-html-element)

Comment: It's quite dirty but you could add your background by using inline css and access it via javascript

Comment: @Hisato but I want to scrap a website how can I add this?

Comment: @JaSON thanks ,I'm trying....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it by tinycss but I got errors , so I changed my mind and I solve it by cssutils BeautifulSoup ,here you can see completer source:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
import cssutils
import string



image_adress=''
with open('/home/azimi/my.html') as webpage:
    html = webpage.read()
    soup = BSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for styles in soup.select('style'):
    css = cssutils.parseString(styles.encode_contents())
    for rule in css:
        if rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
            style = rule.selectorText
            if style == '#container_container':
                for item in rule.style:
                    propertyname = item.name
                    value = item.value
                    if propertyname == 'background':
                        back_vals = item.value.split(' ')
                        image_adress = back_vals[1]
                        print("Image :"+ image_adress)
```